# Eliminar parte de un conjunto de tuplas que forman un array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, estamos haciendo un pequeño programa en Python y queremos eliminar el primer elemento de las distintas listas anidadas. El código es este:

```
puntuados = [[calcularFitness(i), i] for i in poblacionNueva] #Calcula el fitness de cada individuo, y lo guarda en pares ordenados de la forma (5 , [1,2,1,1,4,1,8,9,4,1])
def takeSecond(puntuados):
    return puntuados[0]
puntuados = sorted(puntuados, key=takeSecond) 
poblacionNueva = puntuados
```

Esto es lo que nos sale como salida y queremos eliminar el primer valor de cada tupla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, no veo ninguna tupla en la salida. Podrías pasarlo a código, las imágenes son difíciles de observar. También podrías dar un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: Como dice César lo que muestras es una lista de listas que a su vez contienes una variable y otra lista cada una, no hay tuplas. Dado por ejemplo el elemento `[None, [1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 8, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1]]` ¿Qué es lo que quieres eliminar, el primer elemento (`None` en este caso) o el primer elemento de la lista anidada (`1` en este caso) ?

Comment: @FJSevilla En esa lista en concreto, el None

Comment: @FJSevilla Sabes como quitar las listas cuya variable sea "None" ??

Comment: ¿Te refieres a eliminar la lista al completo y no solo el `None`? Es decir, si tienes: `l = [[None,  [1, 2, 3]], [1, [3, 4, 5]], [None, [6, 7, 9]]` quieres obtener al final `l = [ [1, [3, 4, 5]]]`

Comment: En verdad convertirlo. Si tengo l = [[None, [1, 2, 3]], [1, [3, 4, 5]] pasarlo a [[0, [1, 2, 3]], [1, [3, 4, 5]]

Comment: @FJSevilla Pasarlo a valor 0.

Comment: Casi que es otra pregunta distinta, pero bueno deberias hacer algo como `l = [[0, sl[1]] if sl[0] == None else sl for sl in l]`, no obstante puede que un simple for sea mejor en este caso. Si tienes dudas crea otra pregunta con la nueva duda. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, a ver si entendí. Quieres eliminar el primer elemento de todas las tuplas en el array. Ojo que lo que estás mostrando es una lista de listas, no una lista de tuplas. Recuerda:

```
>>> tupla = (10, 20, 30) # Paréntesis
>>> lista = [10, 20, 30] # Corchetes
```

Si tienes algo como esto (una lista de listas):

```
[
    [1, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]],
    [2, [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]]
]
```

Y quieres extraer el segundo elemento (lo contrario a eliminar el primer elemento) puedes hacerlo con listas de comprensión:

```
>>> l
[[1, [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]], [2, [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]]]
>>> l2 = [x[1] for x in l]
>>> l2
[[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]]
```

Con esto estoy asumiendo que a eso te referías con "eliminar el primer elemento de las distintas tuplas que forman un array".

En tu caso, asumo que la variable que contiene la salida que estás mostrando es `poblacionNueva`, entonces tendrías que extraer los valores de esa lista:

```
 >>> poblacionNueva = [x[1] for x in poblacionNueva]
```

O guardarlo en una nueva variable para no perder los datos de la original:

```
 >>> poblacionNueva2 = [x[1] for x in poblacionNueva]
```